# How To Get A Value Out Of A DetailsView DataItem Property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am accessing a DetailsView from the following event

```
 public void dvDetails_DataBound(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I am casting the sender to my detailsview like so

```
DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)sender;
```

Now when I look in "dv" I can see the DataItem property has the data I want in it under a field name, but I dont know how to write the code access the value??

The field name is shown in the dataitem property as "_DTMON_F", I tried to say

```
Datetime myDate=dv.DataItem["_DTMON_F"]
```

BUT C# doesnt like the syntax, can someone help me with this?

Comment: The datasource is a dbml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the Datasource of your DetailsView. In case of a SqlDataSource DataItem would be a DataRowView. You have to cast it, then you can access it's column. For example:

```
Datetime myDate=(DateTime)((DataRowView)dv.DataItem)["_DTMON_F"];
```

Comment: It gives me an invalid cast exception Trying to cast to a DataRowView

Comment: Thanks I got it from that info, I have to cast it to the dbml object.

Answer (score 0):

Casting problem perhaps?

`DateTime myDate=(DateTime)dv.DataItem["_DTMON_F"];`

If the data source is a database, you may need to use Convert.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRowView drv = dv.DataItem as DataRowView;
DateTime myDate = (DateTime)drv["_DTMON_F"];
```